# Flask-SocketIO simple communicator works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

Very simple communicator built with Flask works fine everywhere but no in Internet Explorer. On Microcrap browser it returns "405 - Method Not Allowed" error without any additional info. Events never reach the Flask application (no log) so I think that they a blocked or so. Does anyone face this issue ?

Whole code looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'very_secret_word_to_enable_encrytion#'
# eventlet.monkey_patch()
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')


def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')


@socketio.on('chat event')
def handle_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received chat event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('chat response', json, callback=messageReceived)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

and corresponding session.html page body:

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid mx-auto">
    <div class="alert welcome-alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" style="width: 750px;">
        <p><strong>Snicky serverless communicator</strong> for internal network chats out of the public<br/>
           It doesn't save anything, everything you write here will be lost after closing browser session
        </p>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="second-alert"></div>

    <form action="" method="POST" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Your name" style="width: 120px;"/>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Your messages then enter or click" style="width: 400px;"/>
            <!--<textarea rows="5" class="message" placeholder="Messages"></textarea>-->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <h3 style='color: #ccc;font-size: 30px;'>No message yet..</h3>
    <div class="message_holder"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function check_if_msie() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if (msie > 0) { // If Internet Explorer, return version number
                console.log(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
                return true;
            }
            else { // If another browser, return 0
                console.log('otherbrowser');
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (check_if_msie())
            socket = io.connect(location.protocol + "//" + location.host + + ':' + location.port);
        else
            socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

        socket.on( 'connect', function() {
            socket.emit( 'chat event', {
            data: 'User Connected'
        })
        var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val();
            let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val();
            socket.emit( 'chat event', {
                user_name : user_name,
                message : user_input
            })
            $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus();
            })
        })
        socket.on( 'chat response', function( msg ) {
            console.log( msg )
            if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
              $( 'h3' ).remove()
              $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+':</b>&nbsp; '+msg.message+'</div>' )
            }
        })
    </script>
    <script>
        $('document').ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                alerts = $(".welcome-alert");
                if (alerts) alerts.hide();

                $('<span class="badge badge-info">Communicator does not support Internet Explorer yet' +
                  ' and it is hard to say if it ever will</span>').show().appendTo('#second-alert');

            }, 6400); // <-- time in milliseconds -->
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the successful communication via Chrome:

```
(12176) accepted ('10.2.16.95', 58561)
10.2.16.95 - - [20/Jun/2019 08:06:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4713 0.002000
10.2.16.95 - - [20/Jun/2019 08:06:10] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MjpjF_7 HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.001000
(12176) accepted ('10.2.16.95', 58567)
received chat event: {'data': 'User Connected'}
10.2.16.95 - - [20/Jun/2019 08:06:10] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MjpjF_s&sid=09c17b19616b4bf681e07b7ff1cdf032 HTTP/1.1" 200 222 0.002000
10.2.16.95 - - [20/Jun/2019 08:06:10] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MjpjF_t&sid=09c17b19616b4bf681e07b7ff1cdf032 HTTP/1.1" 200 215 0.001000
received chat event: {'user_name': 'smok', 'message': 'here I am'}
```

And here is the same from IE:

```
(12176) accepted ('10.2.16.95', 58750)
10.2.16.95 - - [20/Jun/2019 08:07:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4713 0.002000
10.2.16.95 - - [20/Jun/2019 08:07:55] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 347 0.001000
```

So IE is getting connected but fails to send messages

[image]

Comment: What URL and what request method are giving you the 405 error on IE. And also, what is the `methods=['GET', 'POST']` thing that you added on a couple of the functions?

Comment: I updated my post wit hthe results form 2 browsers to give you better picture. Also don't bother with methods, they are not in use anyway, I just thought about controlling things: what and how is coming but that's the sound of the future, eventually.

Comment: IE is not connecting to socket.io. No idea who is sending the POST request, but I don't think it is the Socket.IO client doing that, since the URL should be `/socket.io` as you see in Chrome. See if there are any error messages in the IE JavaScript console.

Comment: first 2 lines appear when I connect the browser to the app so this is just the request for the main page. Third entry appears when I try to send the message which first tries to connect to socket if it doesn't exist. All 3 lines are produced by IE, I think that Microcrap browser tried to do something unexpected when connecting to the socket which is turned down with 405 by my app. IE javascript console shows just warning of its own generated error page (image attached), network tab shows nothing.